Unable to import custom libs in salt module
I have a module to work in bmi_minion (which is inside a container that is works in Kubernetes) to fetch some data. for this main module, I've written some custom libs which are stored in the same dir as the main module (/srv/salt/_modules).
My custom lib script is like below.
import subprocess
import json
import os
import logging


log = logging.getLogger(__file__)
CACHE_FILE_PATH = '/tmp/cache_hw_type_data.json'


class SystemInfoCollector:
    @staticmethod
    def execute_shell_cmd(cmd):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def get_ipmi_sdr_list():
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def get_dmidecode_list(option='sys'):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def get_ras_data(*args, option=''):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def get_system_info(*args, option='os'):
        ...


class HWTypeCacheData:
    @staticmethod
    def load_hw_type_from_cache():
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def save_data_to_cache(hw_type):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def get_hw_type():
        ...

My issue is, when I import this script as a lib in my main salt module, and ran the same by targeting the ms_minion, I'm facing issue like mentioned below.
My Main salt module
import logging
import re
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

from iaas_asset_manager.device42.client import Device42Client
from dimm_constants import DIMMConstants, DIMMMapping
from system_info_collector import SystemInfoCollector, HWTypeCacheData

log = logging.getLogger(__file__)

__virtualname__ = "dimm_errors"
CACHE_FILE_PATH = '/tmp/cache_hw_type_data.json'


def __virtual__():
    return __virtualname__


def _get_hardware_info():
    # Retrieve hardware information like make, model, and serial number
    dmidecode_bm_data = SystemInfoCollector.get_dmidecode_list(option='sys')
    bm_data = {}
    for data in dmidecode_bm_data:
        key = data.split(':')[0].strip()
        if key == 'Manufacturer':
.......

Error I'm getting when I target the minion
arun.srinivasan@dcim-fault-detection-none-20069166:/srv/salt/_modules$ sudo salt 'salt.bmi_minion.20083693' dimm_errors
salt.bmoi_minion.20083693:
    'dimm_errors' __virtual__ returned False: cannot import name 'HWTypeCacheData' from 'system_info_collector' (/var/cache/salt/minion/extmods/modules/system_info_collector.py)

Note: If I separate the custom lib script into two files containing both classes separately, importing is working fine.
What is the issue with current structure of these files?

if you have modules in folder /srv/salt/_modules  then you may have to add it to  sys.path.append("/srv/salt/_modules") before you import any module - because code may run from different place and it may search your modules in different place.  It seems at this moment it imports different file system_info_collector.py from /var/cache/salt/minion/extmods/modules/

BTW: first in code you could check Current Working Directory - print( os.getcwd() ) - because it is place where it searches your modules

I figured out the issue. sometimes, custom libs are imported and cached in the memory. After new edits, we need to do sync_all, state.apply and restart minion. Unless restart, new changes are not applied to the minions.

@furas that will not work at all, as that path only exists on the master.

I figured out the issue. Sometimes, custom libs are imported and cached in the memory. After new edits, we need to do sync_all, state.apply and restart minion. Unless restarted, new changes are not applied to the minions.
